# Particle Hair renders outside lines

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I've been struggling with hair for some time and I didn't find any solution to my problem, so I decided to try and find a solution here. I'm having a problem when I add a line of hair to scalp that they render in a strange way(out of place).

[image: Line of added hair]

[image: Renderer "SIMPLE"]

[image: Renderer "Interpolated"]

[image: Renderer "Interpolated" - Wireframe]

I'm not sure if this is the supposed to happen but it looks strange to me, even more hard way to make a hair style since when I add more hair to scalp they start to come out of chin, forehead, cheeks, etc.

I would really appreciate any help or insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply (Ctrl A) rotation and scale of your mesh, then reduce the radius in which the children are spread around the hair parent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked.  I had to set radius to 0.01 or 0.02 to get same results as u. Do u think thats normal since u have it set to 0.200?
Link to printscreen [printscreen](http://prntscr.com/hxba0x).

By the way, what does applying to rotation and scale of mesh acctouly do?

Comment: The radius value is relative to the mesh dimensions, so it can vary quite a lot. Applying transormations it means that every variation of loc, rot or scale in object mode is transferred to the vertices, as it were maden in edit mode, so the final object results to be located at (0,0,0), has a rotation of (0,0,0) and a scale of (1,1,1). A lot of functions in Blender require to have theese values to work properly, expecially when animating, simulating physics, fluids, using modifiers and so on.